# angularjs - what happened to $route.parent

Tags: angularjs

Trying to emulate this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/W2C45/6/

but when I call

```
$route.parent(this);
```

am getting error

TypeError: Object # has no method 'parent'

I think it is because the fiddle is using 0.9.. and I am using 1.3.0.

the 0.9 doco describes the parent method of $route this way...

```
     * Sets a scope to be used as the parent scope for scopes created on route change. If not
     * set, defaults to the root scope.
```

What is the '1.3' way of getting this done?

Comment: Ok, i'm a dumbass should have looked at the changelogs.. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#route-service-changes

Answer (score 0):

Actually scopes are 'prototypicaly' inherited. That means that all scopes are automatically inherits all properties of scope where they're located.

So can you describe what functionality you want to get?

Here is [sources at Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/V7Vm5YIEZ8scoLbxJIc4?p=preview) with your Fiddle rewritten in 1.0.3